# Running GWT with SCA components

Tags: java, gwt, sca

I'm using SCA and Frascati in a java project. Until now, it is working well with simple java projects, but now I want to create a Google Web Toolkit project and integrate it with the others.

I'm getting errors when compiling the gwt project with frascati...My question is: do you know how to organize this architecture or how to comunicate my gwt prject with the others components?

Errors:

[image: Errors in console]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GWT runs on the client side - The GWT compiler converts the Java classes to client side Java scripts. So you will need to put all your business logic - Data access, SCA, or anything that runs on the server outside the GWT implementation. Generally these components are kept in the 'server' package folder.

I am not sure what your are trying to achieve with GWT here; but the above errors can be avoided if you create a GWT application using the Google plugin in Eclipse. After the basic project is created an compiled without any error, then you can add other components and libraries to the project.